# Manual shading on WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, 3d, gdi+

I'm trying to make a simple 3d-application that allows user to create some 3d-figures and manipulate them: rotate, translate etc.

So now i want to make shading, but it calculate color of figure's border without gradient.So it looks a bit foreign and strange. So i can calculate brightness that differ in vertices, but i dunno how can i fill my figure, using gradient. For example i have a triangle with same color, but with different value of brightness. So how should I fill it?

Now i'm drawing it like this:

```
    private static readonly float[,] Floats;
    static FillVisualizer()
    {
        Floats = BitmapHelper.GetBrightness(Resources.Shademap);
    }

    public override void Draw(Graphics graphics, VisualizableShape shape)
    {
        if (!shape.IsVisible)
            return;
        double x = shape.Normal.X*128 + 127;
        double y = shape.Normal.Y*128 + 127;
        var brightness = Floats[(int) x, (int) y]; 
        var color = Color.FromArgb(255, (int) (Pen.Color.R*brightness), (int) (Pen.Color.G*brightness), (int) (Pen.Color.B*brightness));
        graphics.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(color), shape.Points.CastToPointF());
    }
```

shademap and "magic constants" was picked from *[this url](http://tfpsly.free.fr/Docs/TomHammersley/phong.htm)*

so brightness is the same for all vertices on my shape piece, this is why it looks bad in some cases:

[image: example]

So here i'm using FillPolygon, but it fill it by a single color, when should fill it manualy using brightness in 3(or 4) points of polygon.

Tell me, please, the simplest way to solve my problem.

---

Added: thants to @bansi, image from his url is i'm looking for.

[image]

so i'l try to use it. I hope it will works.

Comment: doing such a thing in `winforms` with `gdi+` is a pain. Even using `WPF`, you won't feel easy to deal with 3D stuff. Although doing 3D stuff in `WPF` is the easiest way (compared to `GDI+`, DirectX and OpenGL or OpenTK). Also the 3D drawing in `GDI+` is limited because the performance is very poor, the code will be as long as possible and buggy. `GDI+` is designed for 2D graphics only I think.

Comment: you may need to look at [Using a Gradient Brush to Fill Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6fxh562(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @King King, i know it, but as i said, i should draw a shape "manualy", so it's composed by many many simplices, triangles or irregular rectangles in my case. I didn't use WPF because i can't calculate size of Image control. I dunno why, but it's not first time when i'm trying to get size of control, calling ActualWidth etc it returns 0. This is why i've used WinForms with fixed size of PictureBox. Anyway, all my figures are incapsulated in model dll, so i can change it to WPF simply. If i'l get how can i do it on it.In WPF I can't draw using abolute coorinates, but it's indispensable condition